# JavaScript - Reset timer after < 0

Tags: javascript, timer, reset

```
var start = new Date;
start.setHours(14, 0, 0); //2pm

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = start - now;

  //var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Order before " + /*days + "d " +*/ hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " + " for delivery tomorrow";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

At the moment i have this JS which after 2pm it says 'Expired' but i no longer want that and wasnt sure how to just reset the timer and make it start counting towards tomorrows 2pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var local_date = new Date( Date.UTC( d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 14,0) );

var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = local_date - now;
```

Change your codes as given above.
set your local_date variable with local date and time.
local_date is also a time.

You may also ignore UTC as per your requirements.